# How can I prevent triggering an on click event when the actual mouse click didn't start on the target element?

Tags: javascript, events, onclick, onclicklistener, dom-events

I need to capture an `onclick` event on the **parent** element but also ignore it if the click is done inside the **child** element. So if you click directly inside the child element nothing should happen. I managed to do just that in the code below. However, if I **start** the click (*mouse button pressed*) **inside** the **child** element but then **finish** the click (*mouse button released*) **outside** the child element (and inside the parent element) it counts as if the click was done entirely on the parent element. So, even it's a `onclick` event, it's behaving like `mouseup` event (IMHO). The problem with that is that when the user interacts with the child element (for instance, selecting the text inside the child element) it's possible to accidentally trigger the event. What I need is to detect this click event **only** when it starts **and** finishes inside the parent element and outside the child element.

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', my_function);

function my_function()
{
  if(event.target.classList.contains('parent'))
  {
 document.querySelector('.child').innerHTML = 'Click event detected.';
  }
}
```

```css
.parent
{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child
{
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This is the parent element where the click event should be detected.
  <div class="child">
    This is the child element where the click event should NOT be detected. 
    However, if you start your click here (mouse button down) and then finish
    it (mouse button up) outside this element (and inside the parent element) 
    then the click is still detected. How can I solve this?
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely overkill, but it works. I build in a variable to enable and disable the click event.

```js
var stopEvent = false;
var clickedOnChild = false;

document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
  clickedOnChild = true;
  stopEvent = true;
});

document.querySelector('.child').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
  clickedOnChild = false;
  stopEvent = true;
});

document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('mouseup', function(e){
  if(clickedOnChild){
    clickedOnChild = false;
    stopEvent = true;
  }
  else {
    stopEvent = false;
  }
});

document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', my_function);

function my_function() {
  if (stopEvent) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    stopEvent = false;
  }
  if(event.target.classList.contains('parent'))
  {
 document.querySelector('.child').innerHTML = 'Click event detected.';
  }
  stopEvent = false;
}
```

```css
.parent
{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child
{
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This is the parent element where the click event should be detected.
  <div class="child">
    This is the child element where the click event should NOT be detected. 
    However, if you start your click here (mouse button down) and then finish
    it (mouse button up) outside this element (and inside the parent element) 
    then the click is still detected. How can I solve this?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, thank you! All the event listeners I'm using call functions passing parameters to them. Like this `document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function() { myFun(var); });`. So I'm wondering if there's a way to implement your solution but passing parameters to functions instead of declaring global variables?

Comment: The event listeners don't know each other and their scope will allways be fresh when they are fired. A global declaration is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [mousedown event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousedown_event) instead of `click` and it'll work almost exactly the same but without the issue you're mentioning

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('mousedown', my_function);

function my_function()
{
  if(event.target.classList.contains('parent'))
  {
 document.querySelector('.child').innerHTML = 'Click event detected.';
  }
}
```

```css
.parent
{
  color: #fff;
  padding: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.child
{
  color: #fff;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  This is the parent element where the click event should be detected.
  <div class="child">
    This is the child element where the click event should NOT be detected. 
    However, if you start your click here (mouse button down) and then finish
    it (mouse button up) outside this element (and inside the parent element) 
    then the click is still detected. How can I solve this?
  </div>
</div>
```

All i changed here was the event from `click` to `mousedown` and the issue seems to be completely gone.

Comment: Yeah, but it changes the wanted behaviour for the parent element. It now gets triggered without a "complete" click.

Comment: That's true. The issue you're seeing, however, is an expected behavior of the `click` event.

From the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event):


If the button is pressed on one element and the pointer is moved outside the element before the button is released, the event is fired on the most specific ancestor element that contained both elements.

click fires after both the mousedown and mouseup events have fired, in that order.

Comment: This seems insane that this would be considered "correct" behavior. In the very least, it seems like the source element should show the original element that had the mouse down, but it does not.

Comment: Yes, that's a very weird specification, but almost everything related to the web is. Changing the click to a mousedown event did help me in my case. I could drag a slider handle in a modal outside of the slider (and modal), and since clicking outside the modal closes it, overdoing the slider interaction also closed the modal. How stupid. Now it's better.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a click listener to the child and prevent event propagation:

```
document.querySelector('child').addEventListener('click', ($event) => {
  $event.stopPropagation();
});
```

This way, the event doesn't "bubble up" to the parent. Here are the MDN docs:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: Couldn't get that to work... it's behaving like it did before.

Comment: Might be due to the "expected behaviour" mentioned in the other answer's comment: The click event is only triggered on the parent, never on the child, so there's no way to stop it from the child.